# Alfresco - How to get all Child that are not folders Alfresco (Java)

Tags: java, alfresco

i want to retrieve all the file contained in a folder in Java through the getChildAssocs(NodeRef nodeRef, Set childNodeTypeQNames) method...

I want to use it in this way:

```
    Set<QName> types = new HashSet<QName>(1, 1.0f);
    types.add(ContentModel. TYPE_CONTENT);
    List<ChildAssociationRef> filesFolderList = nodeService.getChildAssocs(parentNodeRef, types);       
    for (ChildAssociationRef file : filesFolderList) {
        NodeRef childRef = file.getChildRef();          
        if(!nodeService.hasAspect(childRef, MyModel.MY_ASPECT)
                && !nodeService.hasAspect(childRef, MyModel.MY_SECOND_ASPECT)
                && !childRef.equals(actualDocumentRef)){             
            String fileName = (String) nodeService.getProperty(childRef, ContentModel.PROP_NAME);               
        }                            
    }
```

It returns me 0 results neither files nor folders...what i'm wrong?!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this bit here:

```
types.add(ContentModel. TYPE_CONTENT);
List<ChildAssociationRef> filesFolderList = 
         nodeService.getChildAssocs(parentNodeRef, types);
```

A call to `getChildAssocs` can optionally filter by the association type. However, the type you're passing in is a Content Type, not an Association Type. Association types are things like `ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS`

If you change that first like to be `ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS` then you would get all children (content, folders and custom types), and within that you could check the type (or better use the Dictionary Service to check types or subtypes)

Otherwise, to easily get all of the children of a node with control of if it has files or folders in, use [FileFolderService.list](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/model/FileFolderService.html#list%28org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20java.util.Set,%20java.util.List,%20org.alfresco.query.PagingRequest%29). Simply set the files boolean to true and the folder boolean to false, and you'll get only content items and no folders